# SQLite bind functions performance

Tags: c++, string, performance, sqlite

I'm using a SQLite3 Database in C++ and prepared statements to execute queries on it. I'm currently binding all values as strings with the sqlite3_bind_text() function.

Would the use of the sqlite3_bind_double() or -int() be faster?

Even if it isn't tested, maybe someone has a better knowledge of how the functions might be implemented and therefore has a better clue than me.

Comment: Well, if you want to pass floating point or integer values to the queries, then using the appropriate functions will mean that you don't have to convert the values to strings. Of course, that may be done internally anyway, so the only way to know for sure is to *benchmark*.

Comment: Why are you using strings when the values are not supposed to be strings? Why is there a choice between strings and numbers in the first place?

Comment: They where strings in the beginning. I'm now thinking if it would change anything, if i would refactor it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: but is the datatype of a string, even if it looks like a number (i.e. "123" vs 123) not still a string? In that case your question would change into "does sqlite perform better on numbers than on strings", which is true in general, but depends on your scenario. (An index on a string column performs worse than on a number column, for example)